# Sharing a table cell between other cells HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-table

I am not sure of the best way of asking the question I would like the answer to but I will try my best. Please let me know if I am not clear or you need more information understanding what I want to achieve.

Currently, I have two tables one containing peoples name (represented by person1, person2 ....) and other a comment section. Please have a look here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53441658/peoplecomment.html.

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PersonComment</title>
</head>

<script> 

function toggleTable() {
    var myTable = document.getElementById("commentfield");
    myTable.style.display = (myTable.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
    }

</script>

<body>
<table width="300" border="1" id="people" onClick="toggleTable()">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1"><div>&nbsp;Person1</div></td>
      <td id="cell2"><div>&nbsp;Person2</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell5"><div>&nbsp;Person3</div></td>
      <td  id="cell6"><div>&nbsp;Person4</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell9"><div>&nbsp;Person5</div></td>
      <td  id="cell10"><div>&nbsp;Person6</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="300" border="1" id="commentfield">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td id="comment"><div contenteditable>&nbsp;Your comment here</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Each cell in the first table, containing peoples name contains a function that toggles on and off table 2 the comment section (commentfield).

**Aim of this table**
When user click on cell it should allow them to put comment in the comment section and bind that comment with the cell they clicked and not sure this comment on another cell when clicked.

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to share the comment section between all the peoples, so say for example, if someone clicks on person1 and puts a comment, then someone else clicks on person2, I don't want the comment of person1 to show but instead I want the person to be able to add a new comment for person2. However, when say for example, I click on person1 again, I want the comment that was added to person was to be shown in the comment section.

Little scenario:

[image]

Screenshot 1 is how the app looks like currently.
Screenshots that has orange border on them shows that someone has clicked on person and added a comment.
Screenhots that has green border on them shows that someone has clicked on person and added a comment.
Screenhots that has yellow border on them shows that someone clicked on person1 and show the comment that was added for person1 and then they clicked on person2 and show the comment added for person2.
The last screenshot shows that person2 comment has been edited and now if someone clicks on this there will see the new comment.

Note:
The commentfield cell is editable, therefore allowing people to write stuff

One approach of this would be, saving the comment of each person in a variable allocated to them based on maybe the cell id and loading back the variable value to the comment section.

Having little to no knowledge of programming I am not sure how I can do this, any help is welcomed.

Comment: You need to store the comments somewhere, for example, a MySQL database.  Typically, you need some server side scripting in a language like PHP.  You need to learn some basics in PHP, MySQL in addition to HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to store the comments inside a variable allocated to that person. e.g. person1comment = "I am person1"

Comment: @Henry You need to store those variable on a server if you want users to access to them from the web (using a server-side language, such as PHP, NodeJS, etc.). Example : if you simply store it on client side, other users (from other clients) won't be able to interact with these variables as long as you don't send it and share it on The Internet. More information : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: Thats fine because this is test project that I am working on to learn web development.

Answer (score 1):

You could include forms tag and use them.

They will help to trigger wich `contenteditable` is to be seen (CSSS or JS)

---

[here a CSS example of the idea](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeqyRV)

```css
input+div[contenteditable],
input[name="person"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 9999px;
}
input:checked + div {
  position: static;
}
label {
  /* optionnal*/
  display: block;
}
/* trick to simulate js toggle */

table {
  position: relative;
}
[for="hide"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4.7em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1
}
:checked~[for="hide"] {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table width="300" border="1" id="people" onClick="toggleTable()">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="cell1">
          <div>
            <!-- was the div usefull here ? if not; it can be avoided -->
            <label for="c1">Person1</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="cell2">
          <div>
            <label for="c2">Person2</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="cell5">
          <div>
            <label for="c3">Person3</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="cell6">
          <div>
            <label for="c4">Person4</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="cell9">
          <div>
            <label for="c5">Person5</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="cell10">
          <div>
            <label for="c6">Person6</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td id="comment" colspan="2">
          <input type="radio" id="c1" name="person" />
          <div contenteditable id="p1">&nbsp;Your comment here person 1</div>
          <input type="radio" id="c2" name="person" />
          <div contenteditable id="p2">&nbsp;Your comment here person 2</div>
          <input type="radio" id="c3" name="person" />
          <div contenteditable id="p3">&nbsp;Your comment here person 3</div>
          <input type="radio" id="c4" name="person" />
          <div contenteditable id="p4">&nbsp;Your comment here person 4</div>
          <input type="radio" id="c5" name="person" />
          <div contenteditable id="p5">&nbsp;Your comment here person 5</div>
          <input type="radio" id="c6" name="person" />
          <div contenteditable id="p6">&nbsp;Your comment here person 6</div>
          <label for="hide"></label>
          <input type="radio" id="hide" name="person" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I wanted. However, what do you mean by (CSSS or JS)?

Comment: Also, say for example, if I had a lots of rows/columns taking this approach won't be a good idea, will it?

Comment: @Henry i don't know, contenteditable should be seen when it opens without to have to scroll down the page

Comment: @Henry i meant you sould set this behavior via js and not only CSS wich is not really meant for this, javascript is. CSS was set for a quick demo ;)

Comment: Hi @gcyrillus you see currently you have <div contenteditable id="p1">&nbsp;Your comment here person 1</div> for each person, however if I had a lot more cells say for example 50 is there another way of doing this or will I need to write <div contenteditable id="p1">&nbsp;Your comment here person 1</div> 50 times?

Comment: @Henry well it up the way you want to deal with comments, or you use only one contenteditable and use ajax to load content each time a 'personX' is clicked or you load every data for each at once and hide them all till it is to be seen.